# Angular 1 (Ionic): Passing parameters with JSON data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework here, trying to pass data through a click from one templates to another. The data is loaded through a Service, using $http.get; both templates (or *views*) are under a 'MainController', so I am confused as to why the data won't pass across? 
It worked absolutely fine before I pulled the data with a JSON request, and simply put it in the service.

I think I maybe need to define parameters or something?

It looks a little something like:

**Service**

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
  .factory('exampleService', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
      get: function(callback){
          $http.get('http://json...').success(function(data) {
          // prepare data here
          callback(data);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, exampleService) {

styleService.get(function (data) {
       $scope.styles = data;
      });
...

});
```

**Template. 1**

```
<ul class="list">
      <a class="..." collection-repeat="style in styles track by style.id" ng-click="styles.label = style.style" href="#/...">
        <h2 class="selector">{{style.id}}</h2>
            <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
        </a>
    </ul>
```

**Template. 2**

```
<h2>{{styles.label}}</h2>
```

(I've, for obvious reasons, omitted some code, but it all functions fine expcet the passing of this selected option. )

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the http request succeeded? You don't have error handling there

Comment: Yeah, the list is fully rendered.

Comment: What do you mean by "the data won't pass across"?

Comment: you should add `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.styles = data;` and call the callback also when fail the http request

Comment: The user clicks an item on the list, and it should print into the next view (through ng-model="styles.label = style.style), however this does not print.

Comment: With $scope.$apply I get an error: "$digest already in progress", Console.log(success) plus failure -> "success", so the http request is definitely working.

Comment: what kind of data do you want to pass cross templates? i suppose something like style config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to append *$root.* to the *$scope.* which needed to be broadcast (this also would work across two controllers, for someone struggling with that :) )

Answer (score 0):

I am worried what is **styleService** in your controller, the factory method contains  **exampleService**. Please check that.

My common practice to pass data between templates or views by declaring and using **variables** in the **factory** method as below

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AppData', function () {
    var connectionurl = 'http://localhost/api/...;
    var someobject;
    return
    {
    // the left argument can be of your choice where as the right side will be the name as you have declared above
    connectionurl:connectionurl,
    someobject:someobject,
    }
    });


angular.module('myApp').controller('MainSampleController',
function ($scope, $http, AppData) {

// use the AppData variables for binding to 
    $scope.connectionurl= AppData.connectionurl;
    AppData.someobject= $scope.JsonObject;

});

angular.module('myApp').controller('AnotherSampleController',
function ($scope, $http, AppData) {

    $scope.JsonObject=AppData.someobject;

});
```